# Mirroring legacy FlashFiler2 database to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I maintain a very old data acquisition system which uses a legacy FlashFiler2 database. One of my customers would like the database tables to be mirrored into a SQL Server database for easier post-processing.

There are two types of tables:

1. Measured values: these tables get new timestamped data every day and my strategy would be to record the timestamp of the last data record that I have already mirrored for every measuring point and only add the new ones to the target database.
2. Mostly static tables: these tables rarely change and the records don't bear a timestamp. Maybe think of a customers table that rarely gets new entries and the existing records are changed very rarely.

To handle case 2 by brute force, I would have to either clear the target table and recreate it every day or compare each and every record for changes, detect deleted records and add new ones.

What is an efficient way to accomplish this task?

In a related post I found the idea to create MD5 hashes of the target records. The hash could then be used to compare records for changes. Of course I would still have to check for added and deleted records. Would this be worth the effort or should I go with one of the brute force methods?

My tools are: Visual Studio 2017, C# with the ADO.NET provider for SQL Server and FlashFiler2 Delphi components.

Comment: Truncate and Load is a fine pattern, and might be faster than you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following:

1) for all tables that contain rarely changing data I chose to recreate them completely. The performance is indeed better than I had thought.

2) for the measured values tables I chose a configurable lookback from which on the data are chronologically copied to the target database. This is mostly redundant because the lookback by intention should include data that have already been transferred. It is necessary, however, because at times it might be necessary to correct some data in the source that have already been transferred. In my case those corrections usually occur within one or two months. So a lookback of 3 months would usually be enough.

The main performance bottleneck now seems to be my record by record insertion into the target database. I guess there are batch routines for this but that would be a topic for another post.